# phpmyadmin procedures query

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I wanted to create procedure in phpmyadmin but when I run the query I get 0 rows affected. But when I run the query over SQL then it works ok. This is my query:

```
UPDATE 'telesales_anc' 
SET 'TWWID' = (select 'TWW' 
               from 'preference' 
               WHERE 'Status' = 'Active' 
                 AND 'Segment' = 'Telesales ANC' 
               ORDER BY rand() 
               LIMIT 1
              ) 
 WHERE `Lock_ID` = 0;
```

This is a very simple query and I wanted it to rung every day at 02:00 AM (i will set it up I events later. Can you tell me why query won't work in procedures but in SQL it work.

Comment: I guess you forgot to post the procedure's code? And a description what "not working" means (error message? unexpected behavior? etc.).

Comment: well i click under Procedures and then add new routine where i apply this code and click save. Then i click Execute.

Comment: I guess this is MySQL or MariaDB?? You are surrounding most of your objects (tables, columns) with single quote, which turns them into simple strings and make your query a nonsense. Remove all that single quotes

Comment: I try this way but same result. UPDATE telesales_anc SET TWWID = (select TWW from preference WHERE Status = 'Active' AND Segment = 'Telesales ANC' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1) WHERE Lock_ID = 0. This is MariaDB

Comment: Sorry, it say Type: InnoDB